# Youtube video turns upside down while in fullscreen

Tags: youtube

https://vid.me/E5K2 <--- (sorry for the poor video quality)

Youtube video turns upside down while in fullscreen... same result in Chrome or Opera... I actually only use Chrome, and Installed Opera just to try it there.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI5wK.png] (no extension, newly installed)

OS is Windows 10 64bit

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add a link to the original video.

Comment: What Add-ons / Extensions is your browser using? Try disabling them all? Try with a brand new empty profile? Is it using a flash player or HTML5? If flash, is it up-to-date? (May not matter, but is it Win/Mac/Linux?)

Comment: @Xen2050 https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI5wK.png (Opera - no extension, newly installed)

Comment: @DavidPostill You asked the OP to update the question with a link to the video but [the host vid.me is closed](https://vid.me/). I wonder how useful this question is now, but it has one new answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm calling it - It's a **bug** in Chrome, and since Opera's based on Chromium it's apparently inherited the bug too. A different browser family should work, Firefox, Edge(MS), [Midori](http://midori-browser.org/) (based on webkit, like Safari & Chrome, but a different fork I think?)...

Could try downgrading to an earlier version that doesn't have the bug, or wait for a fix... Shouldn't take too long, people seem to complain loudly when their youtube videos go funny.

You're definitely not the only person to start complaining, about 3 days ago too:

- [Google Chrome Help Forum - Why Youtube video rotates while in fullscreen?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/NmkBymWYDho/uixx5lwtCwAJ)
- [Windows 10: Build 15058: screen upside down when I choose full screen video online](https://www.tenforums.com/windows-insider/79451-build-15058-screen-upside-down-when-i-choose-full-screen-video-online.html)

  - Not too helpful, but funny comment "*Perhaps you are using an Australian version of youtube[image: :-)]?*"
- [Youtube - display rotation bug in chrome windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzQRej2twwg)